# Voice call recording Application in android

Tags: android

I like to make an application for recording voice call.Is it possible? I expecting some proper guiding from well experienced people in android.

i have seen android.media.MediaRecorder class in android. Is that class i need to use for this?

Thanks and Regards

Parvathi Kamalone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developers do not have access to the in-call audio stream, sorry. The only way this sort of works is if the device is in speakerphone mode.

Comment: Is it possible in rooted phones?